# Android /config directory lists files where .exists() == false?

Tags: android, file, exists

My Android 2.2.2 file system shows a /config containing lost+found, public, and wifi.  However, .exists() on a new File() for any of those paths returns false.  Is this a bug in Android, or in my understanding?   I don't see any File methods for checking for special files.. maybe I missed something elsewhere?

Comment: how are you getting the file paths?

Comment: listFiles() on /config.  Hmm.. the doc says it return "abstract pathnames" .. what the heck are those?  Maybe I just try list() ..

Answer (score 0):

Only `root` can list files in `/config` folder. Your application don't have permissions to read content and get list of files from this folder.

```
C:/Users/inazaruk> adb shell
$ ls -l /

dr-x------ root     root              2011-05-12 20:30 config
drwxrwx--- system   cache             2011-05-12 23:35 cache
....
```

Comment: $ adb shell
$ ls -l /
drw-rw-rw- root     root              1969-12-31 16:06 config

Comment: "x" permission for directory means "permission to list the files". You don't have one. FileExpert might use SU (if your phone is rooted).

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why you have drw-rw-rw- permission on /config directory. If you was the one who modified it, just add 'x' to each part.